# Swagger works on heroku with HTTP, not with HTTPS

Tags: laravel, swagger

I made a Swagger, and try to deploy it to Heroku.

This swagger has been made with this package [swagger for laravel](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger).

It works fine on my localhost (http://localhost:8000/api/documentation).

I tried to deploy this Swagger on Heroku. It works fine with HTTP, and failed with HTTPS.

The error, with HTTPS, is :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://school-back.herokuapp.com/api/documentation' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://school-back.herokuapp.com/docs/asset/swagger-ui.css?v=8db32e4681a17f1b67d7ae8ca54724eb'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I understand the problem. My question is how to parameter the swagger, or the conf of this package, to not have this kind of problem ?

Comment: Do you have an `APP_URL` environment variable set? What's the value of that?

Comment: Yes I have this variable , content = https://school-back.herokuapp.com. . You think the problem is in this variable ? I doubt...

Comment: I believe this solution can help you,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463050/how-to-load-the-laravel-l5-swagger-ui-over-an-https-connection-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Update your `APP_URL` env variable to `APP_URL=https://school-back.herokuapp.com`. I suspect because you're not including a protocol the framework has to guess what you mean when referencing your static assets.

Comment: I modified this env variable like you suggested. Without success. I also tried to change some config on proxy parameters like written here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#trusting-the-load-balancer without success.