# How to load the Laravel L5 swagger UI over an HTTPS connection on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, swagger, swagger-ui, laravel-api

I tried loading my Laravel L5-swagger URL on heroku, but i get and blank screen. On checking inspect view with chrome i found the error below

```
https://MY_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/api/documentation' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://MY_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/docs/asset/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js?v=2fb7deffbc136bc6540eb1aa890ca736'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have set the following env variables on heroku to the apps domain

```
APP_URL=
L5_SWAGGER_BASE_PATH=
L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST=
```

but no changes still.

NOTE: It works when I open the documentation page over HTTP, but I am looking to make it work over an  HTTPS connection. Please any suggestion or advice would be helpful. And is it ok to leave it over an HTTP connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because l5-swagger is loading your assets with an absolute path by default, in your config/l5-swagger.php you have this by default :

```
'use_absolute_path' => env('L5_SWAGGER_USE_ABSOLUTE_PATH', true),
```

change it to false here or in your env

Answer (score 0):

Step 01 : add to .env in producion `L5_SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS = false` or local  `true`

Step 02 :  add in `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
 public function boot()
    {
        if($this->app->environment('production')) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```